# Java very unusual classpath problems

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I'm trying to run an application that has native libraries and stuff using the following code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("javaw",
    "-classpath", 
    binDir + "polyrd.jar;" + binDir + "lwjgl.jar;" + binDir + "lwjgl_util.jar;",
    "-Djava.library.path=" + nativesDir,
    "monster860.polyrd.Polyrd");
```

I tried doing the equivalent in the command line, changing it to -cp, just using `bindir` instead of `binDir + "polyrd.jar;" + binDir + "lwjgl.jar;" + binDir + "lwjgl_util.jar;"`, and switching between java and javaw, but no matter what I did it gave me:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: monster860/polyrd/Polyrd
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: monster860.polyrd.Polyrd
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone help?

My operating system is Windows Vista.
Yes, those files actually exist.

Here's how I got `binDir` and `nativesDir`:

```
public ProcessRunnable(File nativesDir, File binDir) {
        try {
            this.nativesDir = nativesDir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator;
            this.binDir = binDir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator;
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

EDIT:
Well, of course, it's has absolutely nothing to do with this, but the downloader downloading only the first 2 KB of the file.

Comment: Well, what is `binDir`, what operating system are you running on, do all those files actually exist, etc?

Comment: What about using an IDE?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Must be everything is in the same dir. So he save the dir location seperatly and add it to this String. I am sure it stand for the folder location where the jar files are saved

Comment: Do you know in which jar is located the `monster860/polyrd/Polyrd` class ?

Comment: Post your exact command line or your script, please

Comment: @Aubin The exact command line? I was starting it through the ProcessBuilder class. But it says: `javaw -classpath C:\Users\mnmaxim\polyrd\bin\polyrd.jar;C:\Users\mnmaxim\polyrd\bin\lwjgl.jar;C:\Users\mnmaxim\polyrd\bin\lwjgl_util.jar; -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\mnmaxim\polyrd\bin\natives\ monster860.polyrd.Polyrd`

Comment: @OP: Why don't you move with an IDE? It will make these issues solved in seconds!

Comment: @monster860: He is asking for the full StackTrace

Comment: @Yohan I use the eclipse IDE, but I wanted to make a launcher (for reasons).

Comment: Open the jars with an archiver (7zip, winzip, winrar...) and look for your class to be sure it exists

Comment: @monster860: an installer?

Comment: @Aubin I looked in it with 7zip, and it's there, the method is "Deflate", and the version is 20.

Comment: are you sure its path is "monster860/polyrd"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Java 6, "As a special convenience, a class path element containing a basename of `*` is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files in the directory with the extension `.jar` or `.JAR`". See the [`java`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) command-line options for details.

Addendum: This example starts [`JFreeChart`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) using the wildcard feature mentioned.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15121864/230513 */
public class PBTest {

    private static final String baseDir = "/opt/jfreechart/";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-cp",
            baseDir + "lib/*:" + baseDir + "jfreechart-1.0.14-demo.jar",
            "demo.SuperDemo");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
            String s;
            // read from the process's combined stdout & stderr
            BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((s = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            System.out.println("Exit value: " + p.waitFor());
            p.getInputStream().close();
            p.getOutputStream().close();
            p.getErrorStream().close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

Addendum: Here's the changes for Windows, which requires `;` as a path separator.

```
private static final String baseDir = "C:/Users/Public/JFreeChart/";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-cp",
        baseDir + "lib/*;" + baseDir + "jfreechart-1.0.14-demo.jar",
        "demo.SuperDemo");
```

Comment: I had a hard time understanding that, but I tried `bindir + "*"` and it doesn't work.

Comment: That's what it is, I used `File.getCanonicalPath()` and appended "/" to it, and assigned that as "binDir".

Comment: Are you concatenating `getCanonicalPath()`, `/` and `*`? May you could update your question to show you current approach.

Comment: Well, what I did is set `binDir` as `File.getCanonicalPath()`, and when trying your approach, I added `*` in the ProcessBuilder constructor.

Comment: I've added a working example above; note my OS uses `:` to separate paths, yours uses `;`.

Comment: Funny thing is: I tried to extract one of the classes with 7zip and it said unsupported compression method.